# Google Cloud SDK installation changed bashrc with incorrect syntax

Tags: bash, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

At the end of Google Cloud SDK installation. The installer showed this

```
The Google Cloud SDK installer will now prompt you to update an rc
file to bring the Google Cloud CLIs into your environment.

Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use
[/root/.bashrc]:
Backing up [/root/.bashrc] to [/root/.bashrc.backup].
[/root/.bashrc] has been updated.
Start a new shell for the changes to take effect.
```

But after the update whenever I open a terminal. it throws an error

```
bash: /home/tessact/.bashrc: line 117: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: /home/tessact/.bashrc: line 117: `fi'
tessact@tessact-sys-1:~$
```

So I checked the .bashrc file. few lines were added in the last by the installer, which is given below.

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
#
# I am guessing the code below this was added by the installer
#
  source '/home/tessact/libs/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
  source '/home/tessact/libs/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
fi

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f /home/tessact/developer/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc ]; then
  source '/home/tessact/developer/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f /home/tessact/developer/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc ]; then
  source '/home/tessact/developer/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
fi
```

As we can see the code bloc kshown below starts with no "if" statement

```
  source '/home/tessact/libs/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
```

Was there an error in the installation? Can I just remove the two fi statements which are causing the error

Comment: Yes, it's an error. Can you file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/entry ?